# Defined attributes that are seemingly not used at all for instance objects of some loss classes

Tags: python, tensorflow

I will try to explain my question using an example.
Consider the [definition of the BinaryCrossentropy loss class](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e6784e4302c7b8cd116b74a784f4b78d60e83c26/keras/losses.py#L576) as shown in the following.

```
@keras_export("keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy")
class BinaryCrossentropy(LossFunctionWrapper):
    def __init__(
        self,
        from_logits=False,
        label_smoothing=0.0,
        axis=-1,
        reduction=losses_utils.ReductionV2.AUTO,
        name="binary_crossentropy",
    ):
        super().__init__(
            binary_crossentropy,
            name=name,
            reduction=reduction,
            from_logits=from_logits,
            label_smoothing=label_smoothing,
            axis=axis,
        )
        self.from_logits = from_logits
```

Why defining the attribute of `from_logits` for an instance object?
My understanding is that for an instance object, the attributes of `fn`, `name`, and `reduction` are assigned within the `__init__` method of `LossFunctionWrapper` ([Source code for LossFunctionWrapper](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/b2dafcfa74c5de268b8a5c53813bc0b89cadf386/tensorflow_addons/utils/keras_utils.py#L24)) by passing the corresponding arguments to `super().__init__` from inside the `__init__` method of the loss class (BinaryCrossentropy in this example).
The rest of the keyword argumets (from_logits, label_smoothing, and axis) are assigned to `self._fn_kwargs` to be passed on to `fn` when the instance is called.

Why does an instance object of BinaryCrossentropy need to have the attribute of `from_logits` while (my understanding is that) this attribute is not used anywhere except within `fn`, which is already provided with the required value? The BinaryFocalCrossentropy class seems to have a similar issue. I would be grateful if someone could please clarify.

Comment: How do you know that no possible subclass of `BinaryCrossentropy` will ever need that value?  There's essentially zero cost in storing that for later.

Comment: @TimRoberts I never thought of that potential benefit. Thanks for sharing.